# str_detect(string = "", pattern = "^.*") returns FALSE

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I expected `str_detect` (v1.0.0) could match anything with the pattern `^.*` since the `*` should match 0 or more times. However, `str_detect(string = "", pattern = "^.*")` returns `FALSE`.

Why doesn't it return `TRUE`, and is there an alternative pattern that would always return `TRUE` no matter the string (but still using `str_detect`)?

Comment: According to http://www.regexpal.com/ this search string "matches 0 or more characters" so it throws an error as there are an infinite number of matches possible (regardless of the search space).  I don't know if the same thing is true in R, but that'd be my guess.

Comment: That page returns "infinite" for a lot of perfectly valid regexes.

Comment: I tried `str_detect(string = "", pattern = "^$")` which also returns 
`FALSE`. I would assume there is an early out somewhere hidden in the code.  Which makes it impossible to use the empty String. Especially, as `str_detect(string = "ab", pattern = "a.*b")`
returns `TRUE`

Comment: From what I know you should be safe with `str_detect(string = "", pattern = "^.*$")` - just use both the anchors.

Comment: @stribizhev: I just tried your expression and it returned `FALSE`.

Comment: I ended up writing a wrapper around `str_detect` to check such cases with an or expression `... | string == ""`.

Comment: Is there actually a good reason why you are not using `grep(".*","")`

Comment: @CAFEBABE: Nope, if `grep` can return a `logical` directly.

Comment: @wdkrnls this seems like a bug. Report on github, perhaps?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? It seems you need just `is.character("")`.

Comment: @wdkrnls `grepl()` is the version of `grep()` that returns a logical result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As an answer to not clutter the comment section. However, I have the feeling I'm still missing something)

If the only constraint is that the return value is a logical. You can use

```
grepl(".*","")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I'm really wondering why this got down voted. Based on the discussions this looks like a proper solution to me.

Comment: If you change your code to use `grepl` I'll accept it. That way I don't have to define a new function (I didn't downvote it, though).

Comment: Despite the discussion the original question still says the answer should use `str_detect`. Maybe that's the downvote.